# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Laravel 5.7 trying to connect MsSQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5, pdo

I am trying to connect to MSSQL server but unable to do so.

I have a configuration like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=PRATIK-PC\SQLEXPRESS
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=helical
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=12345
```

This is my `.env` file configuration

Also tried to make changes in `php.ini` file
Added 2 extensions in it

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
```

Please help

Comment: psql can connect with this options?

Comment: @IvanBolnikh I don't know.